# Are there any real examples of Sybil attack?

Tags: security, attacks

I have seen many articles and blog posts talking about Sybil attack but except the case of Tor ([Article Link](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20151201/07281232952/tor-devs-say-theyve-learned-lessons-carnegie-mellon-attack-worries-remain-that-theyre-outgunned-outmanned.shtml)), i couldn't find any relevant articles pointing to the Sybil attack on Computer Networks in real life.

Can anyone suggest some case studies for the same ?

Thanks.